# How to get the name of the branch which was just merged to master?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

My branches are of this format `fix/xxx`, `feat/xxx` and `release/xxx`.

Depending on which branch just got merged to master, I want to create a new tag. Patch, minor and major respectively.

On the master's pipeline, I need to know the name of the branch which was just merged, so that I can bump the right version.

If this is not possible then what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merge `feat/xxx` branch into master using [Merge Request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/merge_requests/), the `CI_COMMIT_TITLE` environment variable has the following format : `Merge branch 'feat/xxx' into 'master'`

You can extract the value of the source branch in a script in your pipeline, here is an example in python :

```
commit_title = os.environ.get("CI_COMMIT_TITLE").split()
source_merge_branch = commit_title[commit_title.index('into')-1].strip('\'')
```